# Erro ao preencher data source Crystal SubReport

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

Estou criando um relatório em c# usando o SAP Crystal Reports, meu relatório contem um subReport quando eu visualizo o relatório pelo Visual Studio no mode de edição do relatório ele preenche os dados no subReport normal, porem quando chamo ele no programa ele só traz os dados só relatório principal e não traz do subReport. Segue abaixo o código que estou usando para chamar o relatório.

```
DataTable dtReceituario = _objAgroReceituarioControl.ImpressaoCabecalho(ReceituarioID);
        DataTable dtItens = _objAgroReceituarioItensControl.ImpressaoReceituario(ReceituarioID);
        _objCrypto = new clsConfigXml();

        CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument rpt = new ReceituarioAgrotech();



        ParameterFields paramFields = new ParameterFields();
        ParameterField paramField1 = new ParameterField();
        ParameterField paramField2 = new ParameterField();
        ParameterField paramField3 = new ParameterField();
        ParameterField paramField4 = new ParameterField();

        ParameterDiscreteValue Agronomo = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
        ParameterDiscreteValue Endereco = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
        ParameterDiscreteValue CPF = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
        ParameterDiscreteValue CREA = new ParameterDiscreteValue();

        Agronomo.Value = objConfigInfo.Config_Agronomo_Nome;
        paramField1.ParameterFieldName = "Agronomo";
        paramField1.CurrentValues.Add(Agronomo);
        paramFields.Add(paramField1);

        Endereco.Value = objConfigInfo.Config_Agronomo_Endereco;
        paramField2.ParameterFieldName = "Endereco";
        paramField2.CurrentValues.Add(Endereco);
        paramFields.Add(paramField2);

        CPF.Value = objConfigInfo.Config_Agronomo_CPF;
        paramField3.ParameterFieldName = "CPF";
        paramField3.CurrentValues.Add(CPF);
        paramFields.Add(paramField3);

        CREA.Value = objConfigInfo.Config_Agronomo_CREA;
        paramField4.ParameterFieldName = "CREA";
        paramField4.CurrentValues.Add(CREA);
        paramFields.Add(paramField4);

        rpt.SetDatabaseLogon(_objCrypto.Usuario, _objCrypto.Senha, _objCrypto.Servidor, _objCrypto.BancoDados);
        rpt.SetDataSource(dtItens);

        FrmVisualizaRelatorios frmViewRell = new FrmVisualizaRelatorios();

        CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument rptDadosReceituario;
        rptDadosReceituario = rpt.OpenSubreport("vDadosReceituario.rpt");
        rptDadosReceituario.SetDatabaseLogon(_objCrypto.Usuario, _objCrypto.Senha, _objCrypto.Servidor, _objCrypto.BancoDados);
        rptDadosReceituario.SetDataSource(dtReceituario);

        frmViewRell.crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt;
        frmViewRell.crystalReportViewer1.ParameterFieldInfo = paramFields;
        frmViewRell.ShowInTaskbar = false;
        frmViewRell.ShowDialog();
```